# DROOLS - use XPath to search a Document for a Node that matches a pre-defined ArrayList

Tags: java, xpath, drools

I have one composite Object being inserted into my KieSession. This object is composed of a pre-created Document from an xml file, an XPath, and expression that I am trying find inside the DOM. I am able to match a single expression, but I am trying to modify the rule so that it will search the DOM for all Strings located in a list. Thank you.

This is the Object that will be initialized and inserted into the KieSession

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Person {
    private String expression;
    private XPath xPath;
    private Document dom;
    private List<String> validExpressions = new ArrayList<>(); 

}
```

In my Drools file, I am able to use the xPath parser to search the Document and find if any of the nodes have a name that matches the expression. However, What I want to do is be able to run the same search but iterating through all of the items in the ArrayList and have the rule fire if any of them are a match.

```
import javax.xml.xpath.XPath;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpression;
import javax.xml.xpath.XPathConstants;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;


rule "Person Matcher"
when
    Person($xp : xPath)
    Person($ex : expression)
    Person($dom : dom)
    Person($validExpressions: getValidExpressions())
    Person(((NodeList) $xp.compile($ex).evaluate($dom, XPathConstants.NODESET)).getLength() == "1")
then
    System.out.println("MATCHED ONE OF THEM");
end
```

In the above example, lets say that my XML DOM has a node "height", if when I insert the fact into the kiesession and fire the rules, I set the expression to "height", then this rule will correctly fire. However, I want to be check through all of the validExpressions instead. I have tried using from, accumulate, but can't seem to get anything to work. Is there any way to get this to work like this?

Comment: Your syntax is wrong to start, but the Drools experts here are not likely to be xpath experts. Can you show how you'd do this check in Java? I can only fix your existing syntax, or translate an example, not come up with one from scratch unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

New line in drools (between object selectors) acts like logical and. You are looking for cartesian match of 5 objects with different parameters. Probably you meant something like this (didn't test)

```
rule "Person Matcher"
when
    Person($xp : xPath,
        $ex : expression,
        $dom : dom,
        $validExpressions: getValidExpressions(),
        $nodeList: ((NodeList) $xp.compile($ex).evaluate($dom, XPathConstants.NODESET),
        $nodeList.getLength() == 1
    )
then
    System.out.println("MATCHED ONE OF THEM");
end
```